# What is good practice when inserting a row with data from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called MAIN that holds overall information about a tournament (name, creator, etc.)

Another table called PLAYERS holds information about players in the tournament (name, age, etc.)

A third table called MATCHES holds information about matches (home and away player, which tournament the match belongs to, etc.)

A fourth table is called ARENA (name of the arena, location, etc.)

When I want to insert a new row to the **MATCHES** I need:

- An id from **MAIN** to connect the match to a tournament
- Two id:s from **PLAYERS** to connect the home contender to a player and to connect the away contender to another player
- An id from ARENA to pair an arena with the match

Let's say I want to create a match in the tournament called "Test" between the players "John" and "Roger". The match will be played at "Wembley stadium".

This means I need one call to **MAIN** to get the id for "Test", two calls to **PLAYERS** to get the id:s for "John" and "Roger" and one call to **ARENA** to get the id for "Wembley stadium".

**How would you solve this? What do you think is the best practice for this kind of task?**

My current solution is using multiple "SELECTS", but I don't think that is the best way to go:

```
INSERT INTO matches (tournamentId , homeId , awayId , arenaId ) VALUES (
    ( SELECT id FROM main WHERE name LIKE 'test' ) ,
    ( SELECT id FROM players WHERE name LIKE 'John' ) ,
    ( SELECT id FROM players WHERE name LIKE 'Roger' ) ,
    ( SELECT id FROM arena WHERE name LIKE 'Wembley' )
)
/* Don't worry about error handling,
* like "if there is no John" or
* "if it returns multiple rows".
* I got that bit covered =D
*/
```

---

Here's the whole code:

```
START TRANSACTION;

/* Create tournament */
INSERT INTO main ( name ) VALUES ( 'test' );

SET @id := LAST_INSERT_ID();

/* Create players */
INSERT INTO players ( mainId , name ) VALUES 
( @id , John ) ,
( @id , Roger );

/* Create arena */
INSERT INTO arena ( mainId , name ) VALUES
( @id , 'Wembely stadium' ) ,
( @id , 'Some other stadium' );

/* Create matches */
INSERT INTO matches ( mainId , homePlayerId , awayPlayerId , arenaId ) VALUES 
( @id , ( SELECT id FROM players WHERE name LIKE 'John' AND mainId = @id LIMIT 1 ) , ( SELECT id FROM players WHERE name LIKE 'Roger' AND mainId = @id LIMIT 1 ) , ( SELECT id FROM arena WHERE name LIKE 'Webley stadium' AND mainId = @id ) ) ,
( @id , ( SELECT id FROM players WHERE name LIKE 'Roger' AND mainId = @id LIMIT 1 ) , ( SELECT id FROM players WHERE name LIKE 'John' AND mainId = @id LIMIT 1 ) , ( SELECT id FROM arena WHERE name LIKE 'Some other stadium' AND mainId = @id ) )

COMMIT;
```

*Added some comments to the code*

Comment: i sincerely do not understand how you don't have the information.
If is it a web page, then the user already selected the stadium and the player... I don't say anything about "like" but in my opinion is better to use primary key (better if numeric)

Comment: @m47730 The thing is that the user doesn't select anything. The user creates a tournament and populates it with players (the matches are auto-generated), all in one go.

Comment: still the same. If you have a list of player and random select one, you still already know what to insert into database.
Share the code helps us to understand better

Comment: User creates a tournament. Boom, there's your tournament ID (main I'm guessing?).  It is then populated with players, randomly or manually selected. Boom, there's your player IDs. Which, if the match is auto-generated and it's players are chosen at random, why use LIKE? It should be picking randomly from a list of player IDs.   You should have all the data you need when the match is created before you do the insert.

Comment: --added more code--

Comment: @Phaelaxz I can't pick randomly from all players, because the players are linked to a certain tournament. if you create a tournament, you don't want my players to show in your tournament =)

Comment: Well for that you could pick from just the players associated to the chosen tournament (using a simple Where clause)